# Must I add a license block to all files in a multi file addon?

Tags: python, add-on

When an addon grows it becomes convenient to break it out into modules, do those other modules (`.py` files) also need a license block or is it sufficient to only put it in the `__init__.py`.

Comment: Your question conflates the issue of weather to include a license block in all files with the GPL IMHO. If this is not GPL specific question you could remove that part.

Comment: good point. fixed.

Comment: @ideasman42, so writing Blender addons with the intent to get them in trunk or contrib, it's preferred that each file has a GPL license block?

Comment: if you want the addons to be bundled with  with Blender's default installation then, yes - they have to use a GPL2+ compatible license.

Comment: Regarding GNU licenses, their [how to page](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-howto.html) says the "statement _should_ go near the beginning of every source file" (emphasise mine).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, but it's good practice. All the official Blender addon files have a license block.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845895/putting-license-in-each-code-file

Answer (score 2):

Some projects uses `See COPYING for license` in all their files, instead of full license block (and include a file thus named), but generally they put some information about license in all component source files.